# Undo an Update in AccuRev?

Tags: accurev

How do I undo an update in Accurev? I want to revert to a state where contents of the files are exactly how it was before an "update" operation?

Comment: Bad question. Very limited unclear and general description, no followup to an answer. This is almost an example of how not to write a question.

Comment: On changing the Time Basis I'm able to get to that list of files and on updating my workspace I'm able to get my workspace to that time. How do it make sure this revert/rollback is promoted to all parents in turn?

Answer (score 7):

There are numerous ways to change the contents in your workspace to reflect an earlier configuration.  Based on the limited description where you reference "all the files under CM", I'll make the assumption that you want to roll back your entire workspace as opposed to a select few files.

Question: does *everyone* parented by the same stream as your workspace want to roll back, or just you?  If it's everyone, you can change the time basis of that parent stream to reflect the specific point in time you want to revert to.  Once that is done, run Update, and you're good.  If it's just you and it's more than a small sampling of files, I'd suggest creating a personal time-based stream, setting the time to *when* you want, and re-parenting your workspace to it:

Current_parent -- New_personal_time_stream -- your_workspace

There are other options as well if you just want to deal with a few select files, but it seems like this is what you're after...

Cheers,
~James